# Simple form & Cocoon nesting form to select from an associated attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

Nesting forms always seems to mangle my brain. Any help would be appreciated.

I want to make a booking form for a course. The course has start dates associated with it. I want the form to update the course start dates once the course is selected from the dropdown selection in the form. I have this much done. I've added cocoon gem and have the forms all set up but I cannot seem to get the form to generate a list based on the course selected in the form.

Models:

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :user
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :bookings
    has_many :schedules
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :schedules, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
end
```

Form Views

Booking Form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@booking) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
<div class="ice-card">
<!--  <div class="form-inputs">-->
    <%= f.input :user_id, :input_html => { :value => current_user.id} %>
    <%= f.input :user_email, :input_html => { :value => current_user.email}, label: "Contact Email" %>
    <%= f.association :course, label_method: :header, :input_html => { :selected => :course }, :include_blank => false, label: "Course Name" %>
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :schedules do |schedule| %>
      <%= render 'schedule_fields', :f => schedule %>
    <% end %>
    </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Schedule Form partial

```
 <%= f.input :start_date, as: :date %>
```

Comment: So first off: after selecting the course, you would like to show all the possible start-dates of the course, correct? And you say you have that, I am assuming using xhr/ajax? I would assume a booking would be linking a user to a course _and_ a start-date, now in your data-model I do not see how a person could book a specific date for a course? OR: is a booker free to add her own start-date? In which case I would assume a `link_to_add_association` call? (but how do you know which start-date is for which user??)

Comment: No feedback whatsoever? Where my questions complete off the mark? Or is this question no longer relevant?

Comment: Hi nathanvds, Apologies for the late reply. At some stage I got sidetracked from this issue. I think the question is no longer relevant as I managed to get a work around for it. Sorry about the lack of feedback on the question.